# Hit and Blow game in java

Tags: java

I wrote a code that is Mind Master Game in java.
I was able to write a code to run the Game. This code was able to run but The game did not finish running even though user already enter correct answer or they already reached max game play. I thought how to fix it and try to fix to run well but I was not able to fix. and now, I have no idea how to fix it.
Also, I want to make a file to record how did user play and run this program. I know I need to use FileWriter method but I have no idea how to record a process.

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MasterMind{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  int[] number = makeArray(10);
  for(int i = number.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  int r = (int)(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  int tmp = number[i];
  number[i] = number[r];
  number[r] = tmp;
}
 int playNumber = 4; // digits
 int[] answer = new int[playNumber];
 if(number[0] == 0){
     for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
       answer[i] = number[i + 1];
    }
 }else{
     for(int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
       answer[i] = number[i];
     }
 } 
  ystem.out.println();
runGame(number, answer, 4);
}
private static int[] makeArray(int size){
int[] numbers = new int[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  numbers[i] = generateNumber();
return numbers;
}
 private static int generateNumber(){
 return (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1; // make secret number
}
private static void runGame(int[] number, int[] answer, int playNumber){
int hit = 0;
int blow = 0;
int count = 0;
int maxPlay = 5;
boolean gameEnd = false;
while(!gameEnd){
  hit = 0;
  blow = 0;
  int[] userGuess = new int[playNumber];
  boolean checkValid = false;
  while(!checkValid){
  System.out.println("enter your guess"); //ask user to get guess number
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] inNum = new int[playNumber];
      String guess = keyboard.nextLine();
      int n = Integer.parseInt(guess);
      String putNumber = guess.substring(0, 1); //set 1st
      int digits = Integer.toString(n).length();

      creatArray(inNum,n);

      digits = Integer.toString(n).length();
      if(putNumber.equals("0")){
        System.out.println("you cannot enter 0 first");
      }else if(digits != playNumber){
        if(digits < playNumber || n < Math.pow(10, playNumber - 1))
          System.out.println(digits);
          System.out.println("It is not enough digits");
      }else if(digits > playNumber){
          System.out.println("It is too much");
      }else{
        gameEnd = true;
        userGuess = inNum;
      }
       }
  for(int i = 0; i < playNumber; i++){  //check hit
      if(answer[i] == userGuess[i]){
          hit++;
      }
    }
  for(int i = 0; i < playNumber; i++){ //check blow
    for(int k = 0; k < playNumber; k++){
      if(answer[i] == userGuess[k]){
          blow++;
      }
    }
  }
  if(hit == playNumber){
    System.out.println("It is correct");
    System.out.println("you enter " + count);
    gameEnd = true;
  }else{
    System.out.println(hit + "hit" + (blow - hit) + "Blow");
    count++;
  }
  if(count == maxPlay){
    System.out.println("You reach" + maxPlay + "Game Over");
    gameEnd = true;
  }
}
}
private static void creatArray(int[] inNum, int n){
for(int j = inNum.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
  int d = n / 10;
  int k = n - d * 10;
  n = d;
  inNum[j] = k;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I assume this is an assignment in a Java learning process, so giving new restructured code is not the way to reach your goal. Some code you might want to look at: 1) you also add the number 10, you might want to stop at 9. 2) You never seem to leave your checkValid while loop, which makes it impossible to check the while(!gameEnd) value. Good luck with your puzzle :)

Comment: @Wkrem Thank you for advising me, I did not notice I forget to make checkValid is true... I will try to fix it !

Comment: @Wkrem I was able to stop running game! I appreciated to you. Thank you so much!